# Monitorin emitted signals of Qt on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, signals-slots

I am working on a project in C++ with Qt in Visual Studio. There are multiple level of signal to signal connection.
By saying that, I mean for example

```
//ExampleClass1
connect(this, ExampleClass1::signalToBeConnected, obj2, ExampleClass2::signalToBeConnected);

//ExampleClass2
connect(this, ExampleClass2::signalToBeConnected, obj3, ExampleClass3::signalToBeConnected);

//ExampleClass3
connect(this, ExampleClass3::signalToBeConnected, obj3, ExampleClass4::slotEnd);
```

Just like this example, there are signal to signal connections until the last signal is connected to a slot. Although it is obvious that the triggering signal of "slotEnd" comes from "signalToBeConnected" of ExampleClass1, if exists, I want to be sure that which signals are emitted.

Comment: ´I want to sure the emitted signals` - what does this mean? If you want to see from where a slot is called set a breakpoint to the slot and look at the backtrace.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I edited that part. I already controlled it from "Call Stack" window of Visual Studio. But probably, the part where signal is emitted is running on a different thread. Because none of the function that was entered was not seen on that thread. I never tried to look at other threads stack usage. Maybe that can solve my problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.